# django: use a queryset as modelform initial data

Tags: django

I'm making a settings interface which works by scanning for a settings folder in the installed applications, scanning for settings files, and finally scanning for ModelForms.

I'm at the last step now. The forms are properly found and loaded, but I now need to provide the initial data. The initial data is to be pulled from the database, and, as you can imagine, it must be limited to the authenticated user (via request.user.id).

Keep in mind, this is all done dynamically. None of the names for anything, nor their structure is known in advanced (I really don't want to maintain a boring settings interface).

Here is an example settings form. I just pick the model and which fields the user can edit (this is the extent to which I want to maintain a settings interface).

```
class Set_Personal_Info(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('nick_name', 'url')
```

I've looked at modelformset_factory which *almost* does what I want to do, but it only seems to work with results of two or more. (Here, *obj* is one of the settings forms)

```
Formset = modelformset_factory(obj.Meta.model, form=obj)
Formset(queryset=obj.Meta.model.objects.filter(id=request.user.id))
```

I can't filter the data, I have to get one, and only one result. Unfortunately I can't use get()

```
Formset = modelformset_factory(obj.Meta.model, form=obj)
Formset(queryset=obj.Meta.model.objects.get(id=request.user.id))
```

> 'User' object has no attribute 'ordered'

Providing the query result as initial data also doesn't work as it's not a list.

```
Formset = modelformset_factory(obj.Meta.model, form=obj)
Formset(initial=obj.Meta.model.objects.get(id=request.user.id))
```

> 'User' object does not support indexing

I have a feeling that the answer is right in front of me. How can I pull database from the database and shove it into the form as initial values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure I understand what you're trying to do - if you're just interested in a single form, I don't know why you're getting involved in formsets at all.

To populate a modelform with initial data from the database, you just pass the instance argument:

```
my_form = Set_Personal_Info(instance=UserProfile.objects.get(id=request.user.id))
```

Don't forget to also pass the instance argument when you're instantiating the form on POST, so that Django updates the existing instance rather than creating a new one.

(Note you might want to think about giving better names to your objects. `obj` usually describes a model instance, rather than a form, for which `form` would be a better name. And form classes should follow PEP8, and probably include the word 'form' - so `PersonalInfoForm` would be a good name.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I've understand ... if you want to generate a form with dynamic fields you can use this:

> class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
>
> ```
> def __init__(self, dynamic_fields, *args, **kwargs):
>     super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
>
>     self.fields = fields_for_model(self._meta.model, dynamic_fields, self._meta.exclude, self._meta.widgets)
>
>     class Meta:
>         model = MyModel
> ```

Where dynamic_fields is a tuple.

More on dynamic forms:

1. http://www.rossp.org/blog/2008/dec/15/modelforms/
2. http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/
3. http://dougalmatthews.com/articles/2009/dec/16/nicer-dynamic-forms-django/

Also Daniel's approach is valid and clean ... Based on your different ids/types etc you can you use different Form objects

forms.py

> class MyModelFormA(forms.ModelForm):
>
> ```
> class Meta:
>     model = MyModel
>     fields = ('field_a','field_b','field_c')
>      class MyModelFormB(forms.ModelForm):
>
> class Meta:
>     model = MyModel
>     fields = ('field_d','field_e','field_f')
> ```

views.py

> if request.method == 'POST':
>
> ```
> if id == 1:
>     form = MyModelFormA(data=request.POST)
> elif id == 2:
>     form = MyModelFormB(data=request.POST)
> else:
>     form = MyModelFormN(data=request.POST)
>
> if form.is_valid():
>     form.save() else:
> if id == 1:
>     form = MyModelFormA()
> elif id == 2:
>     form = MyModelFormB()
> else:
>     form = MyModelFormN()
> ```